# Vue.js call transition explicitly

Tags: animation, vue.js

I know the typical way for doing animations in Vue.js, adding the `transition="my-animation"` on the HTML element.

I'm wondering if can I call explicitly that animation form code and not just depending on `v-show` / `v-if`.

I'd like to "shake" a component (A) each time another one (B) is clicked. For that I use a `pulse` transition (from animated.css).

For the moment B dispatches a message each time is clicked.

A receives the message and sets it's property `animate` to true. Then A shakes thanks to, in the HTML:

```
<div id="A" class="animated" 
    transition="pulse" 
    v-show="show" 
    v-bind:class="{ 'pulse': animate }"
 >
```

Onces it's being animated, won't do it anymore, since A's `animate`prop is already set to true. I'd need to reset it to false so on next click the component could shake again.

I've tried with the transition hooks:

```
Vue.transition('pulse', {
        afterLeave: function (el) {
            this.animate = false;
        },
})
```

Comment: When you say animations, do you mean transitions? In that case, you could just apply the same classes vue uses manually: http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html#Example. `my-animation-enter`, `my-animation-leave`, `my-animation-transition`.

Comment: Yep, transition. Then do I need to use `v-bind` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, you could bind the classes: `v-bind:class="currentAnimationClass"` where `currentAnimationClass` could be one of your animation class values.

Comment: thank you, now works half way. I can call it once changing the property binded, but next time user clicks on the button the property is already set so does not make any transition more. I've tried to unset the property in the transition hooks but I still couldn't achieve it. Any advice for that @nils?

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are trying it?

Comment: Sure, check it please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It won't animate (shake) again since the element already has the class. You need to remove it first.

There are probably a couple of ways to accomplish this, using `setTimeout` to set animate to false is a very easy approach.

Using Vue's class binding (ex. `:class="{'bounce animated': animated}"`), run the animation by setting the `animated` property to true, then remove the class the animation by setting it back to false after the amount of time it takes to finish.

Here is a fiddle with exactly what you want to do, using `setTimeout` to set animate back to false after a 1s animation.

https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/xcLrbtzj/

Comment: Other than `setTimeout`, you can also use `animationend` event to reset the animation https://jsfiddle.net/RobertKirsz/muo19o4x/

Comment: @RobertKirsz Cool!

Comment: ++ solution from @RobertKirsz using `@animationend`
see official vue docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Animations