# vue click animation without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, timeout

I want a div to flash in case a user clicks on it. Is there a solution without manually running setTimeout?

Solution with setTimeout:

app.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<style>
div { transition: background-color 1s; }
div.flashing { background-color: green; transition: none; }
</style>

<div id="app" :class="{'flashing':flashing}" v-on:click="flash">flash when clicked</div>
```

app.js

```
const data = { flashing: false }

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data,
  methods: { flash }
})

function flash() {
  data.flashing = true;
  setTimeout(() => data.flashing = false, 100);
}
```

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ang3ukg2/

Comment: When/where do you want to set the time?

Comment: Why not use css `:active`?

Comment: Maybe you can use the mousedown and mouseup events instead of the click event and then benifit from the css transitions?

Answer (score 16):

Similar to [Christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671135/1171539), but in a way that is more idiomattic to Vue. This uses CSS animation applied via bound classes and the `animationend` event.

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    animated: false
  },
  methods: {
    animate() {
      this.animated = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h1 :class="{'bounce animated': animated}" @animationend="animated = false">
    Animate Test
  </h1>
  <button @click="animate">
    Animate
  </button>
</div>
```

All credit to [Robert Kirsz who proposed the solution in a comment to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455472/vue-js-call-transition-explicitly#comment72665089_37503284).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it solves the problem of removing the class at the end of animation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use CSS animations and hook into the `animationend` event:

app.html

```
<div id="app" v-on:click="toggleClass('app', 'flashing')">flash when clicked</div>
```

app.css

```
.flashing {
  animation: flash .5s;
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    background-color: none;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

app.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  methods: {
    toggleClass (id, className) {
        const el = document.getElementById(id)
        el.classList.toggle(className)
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    document.getElementById('app').addEventListener('animationend', e => {
        this.toggleClass(e.target.id, 'flashing')
    })
  }
})
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Powercube/ang3ukg2/5/

This would allow you to reuse the `toggleClass` method for other classes without muddying the application with arbitrary class data and timeouts.

You can find more information about [animation events at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend).